# Why did car go quiter and cut out after fuel change?

Tags: battery, diesel, gasoline

I did a fuel change and during it was concerned that I may have put diesel in my petrol car because it wasn't clear which pipe was which.  However the handle was green and said unleaded so I guess it was petrol I put in.

Straight after starting up I noticed the car had become quieter and within a few minutes of driving the engine cut out and stopped.  however on cranking again it did start up and I was able to drive 8 miles back without stopping although car does seem quieter than before.

In the morning before this journey battery had gone from being idle in cold and I jumped started it so maybe that had something to do with it?

However as I was confused as to what I was putting in and only after fueling did the engine sound quieter and cut out, I'm wondering what the cause might have been?

Since I am in doubt what should I do?

Comment: Not sure in the UK, but in the States, a green handle *usually* indicates diesel. What you describe (the way your engine is running) could easily be caused from mixing diesel (what probably came out of the pump) and gas/petrol (what was already in your fuel tank).

Comment: Actually, I was wrong ... in the States the handle color is yellow for diesel ... I'm a dolt.

Comment: If you had put diesel in (usually the diesel nozzle won't fit in a petrol but it depends on the fuel station and the car) then symptoms would have been different, lots and lots of misfiring.

Comment: I've seen both yellow and black for diesal in the states (where black handle on diesal and green on unleaded...)
I think what happened is you got a bit of bad gas / watered down gas. Happens a bit out here, and the symptoms are similar. I've had that happen to me - car got quiter, chugged a little, almost didn't want to run. Eventually got over it. Try filling up again somewhere else and it should even out. Long as you're able to run you should be fine....